# Getting an error while filtering an entity results using contains (like operator)

Tags: entity, linq-to-objects

Could you please help me to filer a results using contains (like operator) which as following...

```
Public Function GetFromCacheByParentID(ParentID As String, Criteria As String) As List(Of tbl_equip_master) 
Dim RelatedData = _RelatedData.GetFromCache
Dim EquipMaster = Me.GetFromCache
return (From e In EquipMaster, r In RelatedData Where r.linked_for = "EQP" And e.global_id = r.child_id And r.parent_id = ParentID And (e.tag_no.Contains(Criteria) Or e.object_name.Contains(Criteria) Or e.object_type.Contains(Criteria)) Select e)
End Function
```

My intention is calling 2 results from cashed data and try to join and filter using contains

But i am getting an error on ".contains".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trace out the issue, reason is "e.object_name value is Nothing" - data from sql server. so code "e.object_name.Contains(Criteria)" throws an error...

And another question is raising how we can avoid such situation...any idea please...

Answer (score 0):

All issue has solved by using following code by trapping "null" value

`Public Function GetFromCacheByParentID(ParentID As String, Criteria As String) As List(Of tbl_equip_master) 
            Dim _RelatedData As IRelatedDataV2 = New RelatedDataV2
            Dim RelatedData = _RelatedData.GetFromCache
            Dim EquipMaster = Me.GetFromCache
            Return (From e In EquipMaster, r In RelatedData Where r.linked_for = "EQP" And e.global_id = r.child_id And r.parent_id = ParentID And (e.tag_no.Contains(Criteria) _
                    Or (Not IsNothing(e.object_name) AndAlso e.object_name.Contains(Criteria))) Select e).ToList
        End Function`